# Else statement never reach

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i have an if statements align with a query in Linq to create the login in my app, but, the code works bad, when the query don't select any record, the .Count() it's equal to zero and it have sense, but in the if, the code never reach the else part, look, this is my code:

```
var UserLogin = from m in _context.User where m.Username.Contains(this.Username) & m.Password.Contains(this.Password) select m.Username;
                this.Username = string.Empty;
                this.Password = string.Empty;
                if(UserLogin.Count() != 0)
                {
                    //HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", UserLogin.First());
                    UsernameLogged = UserLogin.First();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sisa: " + UsernameLogged);
                    this.Username = string.Empty;
                    this.Password = string.Empty;
                    UsernameLogged = string.Empty;
                    Console.WriteLine(UsernameLogged);
                }
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Are you getting an error or what? The only other reason why your else part is never reached would be because the if block is being executed. Check the value of UserLogin.Count() at runtime and you might get a clue

Comment: Have you manually aligned the code with your Linq query? Don't do that, it's confusing.

Comment: BTW, your comparison of user and specially password has terrible security flaws.

Comment: `m.Password.Contains(this.Password)` - please ***don't*** save passwords as plain text. _hash_ them instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the query is executed twice. The first time when you call `UserLogin.Count()`. The second time when you call `UserLogin.First()`. But then, you already have set `Username` and `Password` to `string.Empty` and all the user names and passwords do contain an empty string because [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_) tests only whether a part of the string matches. So you are getting all the users in the result. Use `==` to test the whole string.

Since you want to get only one user, use [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0) which returns `null` when no user was found.

```
var userLogged = _context.User
    .FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == Username && u.Password == Password);
if (userLogged is null) {
    Console.WriteLine("Sisa: " + UsernameLogged);
    Username = string.Empty;
    Password = string.Empty;
    UsernameLogged = string.Empty;
    Console.WriteLine(UsernameLogged);
} else {
    UsernameLogged = userLogged.Username;
}
```

You are setting `Username` and `Password` to `string.Empty` twice. Either clear them after the if-else if you always want to do so, or do it only when no user was found.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you are using deferred execution of LINQ query. Your query is executed in if condition and there you will get count 1.

Use below code -

```
var UserLogin = from m in _context.User where m.Username.Contains(this.Username) & m.Password.Contains(this.Password) select m.Username;

var count = UserLogin.Count(); // Here your query will be execute

this.Username = string.Empty;
this.Password = string.Empty;

if(count != 0)
{
     //HttpContext.Session.SetString("Username", UserLogin.First());
     UsernameLogged = UserLogin.First();
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Sisa: " + UsernameLogged);
     this.Username = string.Empty;
     this.Password = string.Empty;
     UsernameLogged = string.Empty;
     Console.WriteLine(UsernameLogged);
}
```

This will execute your else condition.